# Convert a text of a specific cell or exclude one cell from all text convertion to UPPERCASE

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

How to adapt this function to exclude a specific cell or how to apply just to one cell?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Convert a text of a specific cell ... to UPPERCASE

- try like this which should upper **Sheet1!A2** cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize;
    sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    colToCapitalize = 1;
    sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart = 2 || e.range.columnStart !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

Comment: user0, thanks for your help. But, and if I only want to exclude a specific cell, in the original script?

Comment: I got this message when saving: Invalid assignment left-hand side. (linha 1, arquivo "macros")Dispensar